# Override bash command and be able to pass it as a param to xargs

Tags: bash

I'd like to be able to pass in a modified grep command to xargs. I am overriding a command with a function in bash similar to [Is it possible to override the command line's built in "cd" command?](https://superuser.com/questions/296551/is-it-possible-to-override-the-command-lines-built-in-cd-command). My function below works, except when passing to xargs. Why is this and how do I work around this?

redefined:

`function grepc() { $(which grep) -c "$@"; }`

works:

```
find -name '*.py' | grepc web
2
```

xargs fails:

```
find -name '*.py' | xargs grepc import
xargs: grepc: No such file or directory
```

(passing to xargs here should grep the file contents of the python list, which is a weird contrived example but the point is xargs can't find grepc)

TLDR: why can't `| xargs <function>` work? Does `<function>` actually need to be a `<builtin>` or something?

Answer (score 4):

Whatever `xargs` runs, it is its direct child process, there's no shell between them. `xargs` has no concept of your function. It also has no concept of shell builtins.

To make it work:

- either export your function (with `export -f grepc`) and make `xargs` run a shell in a somewhat cumbersome way: `… | xargs bash -c 'grepc "$@"' bash`
- or better convert your function to a script, make the file executable and place it where your `$PATH` points to (or adjust the variable); then `grepc` will be a file and `xargs` will be able to run it.

Comment: Nice. I like the second idea better too. I thought of just doing `alias xg='xargs grep'` and `xgc='xargs grep -c'`?

Answer (score 0):

Another workaround that came to me:

`alias xg='xargs grep --color <or whatever else I want>'`

Since I use this combination so frequently.