# How to escape a Bash function

Tags: linux, windows-10, bash, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have the following function in my `.bashrc` file on WSL2:

```
cd() {
    builtin cd "$@" && ls
}
```

I've used this on Cygwin without issue [for years](https://superuser.com/questions/296551/is-it-possible-to-override-the-command-lines-built-in-cd-command), and it works just as well on WSL2, except for one problem: I can't seem to be able to use the built-in `cd` inside of a new alias in `.bashrc`.

If `cd()` was an alias instead of a function, I'd be able to escape it with:

```
alias new="\cd .. && echo 'This is a new alias'"
```

or

```
\cd ..
```

on the command line. But this override doesn't seem to work with the `cd()` function like it would with an alias.

Is it possible to override a function in Bash?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, by using `builtin cd`.

(The equivalent for external commands is `command`, e.g. `ls() { command ls ...; }`.)

---

Note that `\` only works with aliases because their expansion happens *before* backslash handling and other parsing steps, so the shell actually tries to look up an alias literally named `\cd` (which does not exist).

So the trick doesn't work with functions because they act as completely normal commands and are resolved during a much later stage (at which point the backslash handling has already turned `\foo` into regular `foo`).

Comment: I had a hunch about this and now I feel stupid for not actually following it through to its conclusion. Confirmed to be working, and I also didn't know about the `command` command. Thank you.

Comment: @Hashim Funny thing is you needed to use `builtin cd` in the function exactly to escape the function. Without the `builtin` word the function would call itself recursively upon being called.